# How do I send/get a JSON Object with Django?

Tags: python, django, json

I know how to use the JQuery ajax feature to call the "url view" of Django.

```
import simplejson as json
def the_view(request):
    fruits = {'color':5, 'type': 22}
    jfruit = json.dump(fruits)

return render_to_response( THE JSON OBJECT!!! ...how? )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(mydictionary), mimetype="application/json")
```

see [b-list](http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2006/jul/31/django-tips-simple-ajax-example-part-1/)

Comment: Though really the JSON mimetype is `application/json`.

Comment: Good point, I changed it.  Really it's just to eliminate the XSS security problems for returning the default 'text/html' mimetype, so either will work. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Or shorter: 
download http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/ and write:

```
@ajax_request 
def the_view(request):
    return {'color':5, 'type': 22}
```

There are a few such nice tiny things in django-annoying.